# Python error: AttributeError: module 'pyexcel' has no attribute 'get_sheet'

Tags: python-3.x, pyexcel

I am trying to read a excel file and copied this code but it's giving me an error saying `pyexcel` has no attribute `get_sheet` but the documentation and example shows it is there. What am I doing wrong?
Python shell screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I fixed the issue by re-installing pyexcel and it worked.

Comment: There has been a bug with one version pyexcel-io in v0.4.x family but it's fixed and long gone.