# How can I get a dictionary from the contents of a .xlsx file?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pyexcel

I'm trying to use `pyexcel` but am having an issue following the instructions. On the [documentation](https://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_data_conversion.html#how-to-obtain-a-dictionary-from-a-multiple-sheet-book), it says to run this code:

```
>>> import pyexcel
>>> import json
>>> book_dict = pyexcel.get_book_dict(file_name="book.xls")
>>> isinstance(book_dict, OrderedDict)
True
>>> for key, item in book_dict.items():
...     print(json.dumps({key: item}))
{"Sheet 1": [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]}
{"Sheet 2": [["X", "Y", "Z"], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}
{"Sheet 3": [["O", "P", "Q"], [3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2]]}
```

However, my interpreter in Python 2.7 says that `get_book_dict` is not a valid attribute. Any ideas how I should proceed?

Comment: is `import pyexcel` not throwing any error? Is this windows or any other OS?

Comment: Which version of `pyexcel` are you using?

Comment: @AdeelAhmad I am using pyexcel 0.5.0, and no, it imports just fine.

Comment: @user1917407 Paste the complete error message you're getting, not just from the documentation.

Comment: @AdeelAhmad AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_book_dict'

Comment: Please try reinstall pyexcel, see this related error here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103036/python-error-attributeerror-module-pyexcel-has-no-attribute-get-sheet

Comment: please install pyexcel-io v0.4.2, which should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exactly don't know the reason of the error but I got a workaround for you. Try:

```
>>> from pyexcel.core import *
>>> get_book_dict
>>> <function get_book_dict at 0x7fb8cc87d140>
```

I think there might be some problems with [**init**.py](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel/blob/master/pyexcel/__init__.py)

Answer (score 0):

Might work for you, just give it a try

```
pip install pyexcel-xls
```

and then import this way

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> import pyexcel.ext.xls
```

Comment: This didn't work, I'm still getting the same AttributeError as before, no matter if I use pyexcel.get_book_dict or pe.get_book_dict